# CollectionView is initialized before getting data from Database - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a **posts array** which gets filled with data from my Database *(Filling with data is happening in a function in viewDidLoad)*. Later on, a **collectionViewCell** will be configured with that data.

Since the data gets from database with a bit of delay, the function below doesnt return any **Int** value.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
```

I've tested that out in viewDidLoad by the code below

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(posts.count) //TESTED BY PRINTING POSTS.COUNT WHICH IS 0 CURRENTLY
    getVideosNamesAndUsers() // The function which gets data from database and updates posts Array
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}
```

So my cells should be configured with the data coming from **posts Array** but since posts array is being initialized way before the data comes from the database. After data is downloaded from database, it updates post array by that data.

Configuring and reloading cell with code below but nothing happens. My cells are not showing.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let postModel = posts[indexPath.row]
        
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MusicGenresPostsCollectionViewCell().identifier, for: indexPath) as? MusicGenresPostsCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
            
            self.collectionView = collectionView
            cell.configure(with: postModel)
            collectionView.reloadData()

        return cell
    }
```

**Note:** I've registered the cell and added delegate = self and datasource = self. Still my collectionView Cells are not showing. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, `getVideosNamesAndUsers()` is an async function that "gets the data from database with a bit of delay" ... inside **that** function, after you have retrieved the data, you need to call `.reloadData()` on your collection view. A little searching for `reload collectionview after retrieving data` will give you plenty of examples, tutorials, discussions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not call `collectionView.reloadData()` inside of `collectionView(cellForItemAt:)`. The reason for this is that `collectionView(cellForItemAt:)` is ran once for every single cell. So if you have 50 cells, it's being called 50 times. In each one of those 50 times, you're telling it to reload again. So your UICollectionView will infinitely reload as you're calling `.reloadData()` inside of a function that's triggered by `.reloadData()`
2. There is no problem in initializing your UICollectionView before retrieving the data. The problem is that you're not updating the UICollectionView when the data is received, only the variables that store your data.

You have not shown what `getVideosNamesAndUsers()` looks like, but wherever your code would go when the data is finished downloading, you should implement `collectionView.reloadData()`.